# Behavior not firing OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a custom behavior that check an email address

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AllTheSame.Behaviors.Validator
{
    public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        private static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), default(bool), BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get => (bool) GetValue(IsValidProperty);
            private set => SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value);
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        }

        private void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, "^(?(\")(\".+?(?<!\\\\)\"@)|(([0-9a-z]((\\.(?!\\.))|[-!#\\$%&\'\\*\\+/=\\?\\^`\\{\\}\\|~\\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\\[)(\\[(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\\])|(([0-9a-z][-\\w]*[0-9a-z]*\\.)+[a-z0-9][\\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$");
            }
            catch
            {
                IsValid = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                ((Entry) sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

And I used it like this in my XAML page

```
...
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:RegisterViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
...
<Entry Placeholder="Email" Text="{Binding Email}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <validator:EmailValidatorBehavior x:Name="EmailValidatorBehavior" IsValid="{Binding IsEmailValid}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

My page is bind to my RegisterViewModel, and I got a property "IsEmailValid" in it.

```
public bool IsEmailValid
{
    get => _isEmailValid;
    set
    {
        _isEmailValid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        SignUpCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
    }
}

private bool _isEmailValid;
```

The problem is, when I change the text of the entry, the "HandleTextChanged" method in the behavior is executed, but the value of my property "IsEmailValid" in my "RegisterViewModel" is not changed. I'm probably doing something wrong here but I can't figured it out. I tried using BindableProperty.Create in my behavior but nothing changed.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need an INotifyPropertyChanged?
here is an example:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
// boiler-plate
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}

// props
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { SetField(ref name, value, "Name"); }
}
```

}

Comment: Not at all. I'm binding the behavior to my property "IsEmailValid" in my view model. But the value is never get or set by the behavior. I need the behavior to be able to change the property in the viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to set the IsValid binding to two-way.

```
<validator:EmailValidatorBehavior ... IsValid="{Binding IsEmailValid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

If that doesnt work, I would try adding a callback on the bindable property

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = 
BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), null, 
propertyChanged: OnIsValidChanged);

static void OnIsValidChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    // Property changed implementation goes here
}
```